# show that there exists a unique solution to the boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

show that there exists a unique solution to the boundary value problem $(1+x^2)u''+(4x-x^3)u'+(2-3x)u=x$ with boundary conditions $2u'(-1)-u(-1)=0,2u'(1)+u(1)=0$

In order to show that a unique solution exists we can show that the only solution to the homogenous BVP is the trivial one. But I can't seem to solve the homogeneous ODE. We learned in class the Energy method in which we look at $\int uLu=0$ but this doesn't seem to work here. another approach is to transform the ODE into $(p(x)u')'+r(x)u=0$ and to try and bound it from above with $r_2(x)>r(x)$ for the ODE $(p(x)u')'+r_2(x)u=0$ and show that the solution for the latter ODE doesn't vanish in the interval $[-1,1]$. Any hints will be more than welcome.

Comment: If we follow your other approach, the Sturm-Liouville equation we end up with is $[\exp(-x^2/2)(1+x^2)^{5/2}u']'+\exp(-x^2/2)(2-3x)(1+x^2)^{3/2}u=\exp(-x^2/2)(1+x^2)^{3/2}x$.

Comment: @user10354138 how can I find a solution to this equation?